# I want to delete all the numbers that have 1, 4 or 5 in them, but it gives a index error

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, index-error

```
#list 000 to 999
numbers = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    i = str(i).zfill(3)
    numbers.append(i)

num = "145"
for j in range(1000):
    for k in range(3):
        if numbers[j][k] in num:
            numbers.remove(numbers[j])
```

I want to delete all the numbers that have 1, 4 or 5 in them

Comment: You removed some elements of `numbers`, so it no longer contains 1000 elements, so `for j in range(1000)` is no longer valid.

Comment: After you remove an item from `numbers`, it no longer has 1000 items in it.  The best plan when doing something like this is to create a NEW list that contains only the items you want to keep.  And you can rewrite your loops as `for j in numbers:` / `for k in j:` if j in num:`...

Comment: Removing an element from `numbers` makes it smaller (obviously), so the `range(1000)` loop will eventually result in indexes that are too big.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = []
for i in range(0, 10000):
    i = str(i).zfill(3)
    numbers.append(i)
print('1', numbers)
num_del = "145"
for num in numbers:
    for i in num_del:
        if i in num:
            numbers.remove(num)
print('2', numbers)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31042287)

Comment: You're right. That's why I am trying to get enough reputation. @excitedmicrobe

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting elements in the list as you're iterating over it. So, for example, by the time you reach index `999`, there are no longer `1000` elements in the list. (In truth, this out-of-bounds issue happens at a much earlier index.)

Rather than try to modify the list as you're iterating over it, you should create a new list instead. The easiest way of doing that is to use `filter()` to remove numbers on a specified condition; in this case, we remove numbers that contain a `1`, `4`, or `5`:

```py
def contains_forbidden_digit(num):
    for digit in str(num):
        if digit in {'1', '4', '5'}:
            return True
    return False

print(list(filter(lambda x: not contains_forbidden_digit(x), range(1000))))
```